# How do I access my software where my MacBook Air saves all my changes?

Tags: macbook-pro

So I was about 3/4 of the way finished with this big Prezi project. I accidentally deleted all the words, boxes, and titles and refreshed it twice so I can't undo. But I thought that since it says "All changes Saved" in the top left corner, I can access all my changes from Prezi from my software...could you tell me where to access my software, how to edit my Prezi from my changes-software, and if this is all just a lost cause please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Prezi is an online application that runs in a web browser. So the changes are saved on Prezi's servers. They aren't saved on your Mac.

Comment: There are undo/redo buttons near the top-let of the Prezi window. So you might be able to revert those deletions using them.

Comment: What changes-software do you use?